# Angular 2: Child Routes not working by address bar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hei,

I have a working App. When I move to child components by click it works but when I write the path on the address bar it doesn't work.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([               
        {
          path:'',
          component:SiteComponent,
          children: [{              
            path:'portafolio/:id',
            component:OutletComponent              
          }
          ]
        },      
        {
          path:'**',
          redirectTo: '',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },       
        ]),
```

When I navigate to let's say the first portfolio using `router.navigate(['/portafolio', portafolio.id])` it works fine.
But when I want to navigate to the first portfolio by writing on the address bar localhost:4200/portafolio/1 it doesn't work.
It doesn't show a 404 error. Just shows '...' which is what I have between  the `<app-root>` tags in the index.html. The wildcard works fine because any other wrong address redirects to SiteComponent. How do I solve this in order to be able to open a specific portafolio also by writing the path to the address bar?

UPDATE: I changed the routing config to:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([               
    {
      path:'',
      component:SiteComponent          
    },
    {  
      path: 'portafolio',
      component:SiteComponent,
      children: [{              
        path:':id',            
        component: OutletComponent
        }]          
    },      
    {
      path:'**',
      redirectTo: '',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },       
    ])
```

Same behavior. It works fine till I try to use the address bar to access any portfolio.
This is the error I get:

```
2:19 GET http://localhost:4200/portafolio/inline.bundle.js 
2:19 GET http://localhost:4200/portafolio/polyfills.bundle.js 
2:19 GET http://localhost:4200/portafolio/styles.bundle.js 
2:19 GET http://localhost:4200/portafolio/vendor.bundle.js 
2:19 GET http://localhost:4200/portafolio/main.bundle.js
```

This is the bootstrapped Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector : 'app-root',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

This is the OutletComponent definition:

```
@Component({ 
  templateUrl: './outlet.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./outlet.component.css'] 
}) 
export class OutletComponent implements OnInit { 
 portafolios:any; 
 numero:string; 

 constructor(private _router:Router,
             private _activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, 
             private _formservice : FormService) { 
  _activatedRoute.params.subscribe((parametro:Params) => this.numero = parametro['id']); 
   _formservice.data$.subscribe(data=> { this.portafolios=data }); 
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I thought maybe there was something wrong with :id so I simplified and created a TestComponent.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    template: '<h1>Test</h1>',
})

export class TestRoutesComponent {

}
```

And added another Route

```
{path: 'testroutes',component: TestRoutesComponent}
```

Still when I try to access by address bar `http://localhost:4200/testroutes/` I get the same error.

SOLUTION: Ok I created an angular-cli project and this time the route was working with `router.navigate(['/testroutes')` and ALSO with `http://localhost:4200/testroutes/` So I splitted sublime in 2 and carefully looked for a difference and I found this `<base href="./">` different to `<base href="/">` A simple dot was causing the error. When I cloned the project the dot was there or did I put it there for some weird reason I don't know. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: if the app doesn't launch, you must have a error in your browser console. Would you mind sharing that error with us ?

Comment: can you try using it in separate route? ( not child of `''`)

Comment: Omarllias.. Before was not child of X.. Still happened the same. this is the error. mickdev I updated above.

Comment: @RaulBustamante just use `path:'portafolio/:id',` without any children. And what's in `OutletComponent`?

Comment: In order to use that path without any children I had to delete the AppComponent and bootstrap SiteComponent instead. Set index.html to render SiteComponent. And then I can do what u suggest. Now route is: `RouterModule.forRoot([{path: 'portafolio/:id',component: OutletComponent}])` and still doesn't work. Same error when I use the address bar. But I need to use children route because <router-outlet> is withing SiteComponent.html And some parts of it I have to be visible always. And also I need to be able to render SiteComponent or another instead.
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I created an angular-cli project and this time the route was working with `router.navigate(['/testroutes')` and ALSO with http://localhost:4200/testroutes/ So I splitted sublime in 2 and carefully looked for a difference and I found this `<base href="./">` different to `<base href="/">` A simple dot was causing the error. When I cloned the project the dot was there or did I put it there for some weird reason I don't know. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from the question but I assume all the components are defined in a single `AppModule`?

I think you could simplify your routing a bit:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([               
{
  path:'',
  component:SiteComponent          
  children: [
    {              
      path:'portafolio/:id',            
      component: OutletComponent
    }]
},      
{
  path:'**',
  redirectTo: '',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},       
])
```

`SiteComponent` template would need to have a `<router-outlet>` for the child route ('portafolio/:id')

Comment: Hei garth74, Yes what you suggest was my first approach. And yes I have a <router-outlet> inside SiteComponent. Check the Update 2.